# mysql GROUP BY vs multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im not sure how to ask this, but which is better... using GROUP BY or multiple tables.

Currently, I have one table that generates lists. It has several columns, one is a list id.

Right now this is my query

```
SELECT `listID`, `` 
FROM `acmSongLists` 
WHERE `churchID`='".$thisID."' AND `timeSent` >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 0 MONTH ) 
GROUP BY `listID` ASC
```

The point of course is to get all items associated with the same listID. Then I pass that ID to another query in order to display my list titles. AKA...

```
SELECT * FROM `acmSongLists` WHERE `listID`='$listID'"
```

I am curious, Is there a better way of doing this? My other thought was to create two tables, one that holds the general information as well as a unique id (listID) then a second table that holds each item within the list. Then query them respectively. I guess I'd like to know what is the most efficient. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Go with the two tables. If the second table contains only one single item per `listID` (1:1) then you can use a `UNION`, so just a single query that returns data from both tables. If there are multiple items per `listID` (1:n) then use a `JOIN`. I doubt you want to use the `GROUP BY` operator, since it drops entries, so you would get only one single item although many exist.

Comment: Good idea to use a join with two tables. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sandy already did that :-)

Comment: yes but your the one who actually gave me the answer, Ill, mark hers as correct, but if you add yours ill switch it

Comment: All fine. This site is _not_ about earning points. It is about helping each other :-)

Comment: I agree, but I also feel I should always give honor where honor is due. Its all good though...cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT asl1.`listID`, asl2.*
FROM `acmSongLists` asl1 INNER JOIN `acmSongLists` asl2 ON asl1.listID = asl2.listID
WHERE `churchID`='".$thisID."' AND `timeSent` >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 0 MONTH ) 
GROUP BY asl1.`listID` ASC
```